# My cat rubs his eyes on objects all the time

Tags: cats, eye-disease

My cat has this weird behaviour where he will rub his eyes on objects. Like sharp objects some times.

He does this repeatedly. Sometimes for several minutes without stopping.

A video of him doing it on a sharp window handle (not that sharp, don't worry) https://s3.amazonaws.com/uploads.hipchat.com/289068/1805450/8cLboxQairixk3m/VID_20171024_000929.mp4

But when I look at his eyes he looks fine :

https://s3.amazonaws.com/uploads.hipchat.com/289068/1805450/tFmikMs7LhpJuMZ/IMG_20171024_001209.jpg

https://s3.amazonaws.com/uploads.hipchat.com/289068/1805450/QfKQxkX8ygZdKIs/IMG_20171024_001201.jpg

Should I go to the vet ?

Comment: take your cat to a vet it is not easy to give an answer just by seeing a little video and some pictures,but please come back and tell how it goes after the examination at the vet.

Comment: Look for some kind of a rash near the area where the cat wants to scratch. It's rubbing against as a form of scratching

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could see that around his eyes it's reddish. The left and right side of his right eye that is. So is it because of the scratching or is that some kind of rash? It seems you should go to a vet. Or at least try taking him a shower and clean his eye sides real careful with cat shampoo. Baby shampoo is also fine, however whichever shampoo you use you should be very careful not to put it in the cat's eye. If you think you can't do it then you should just take him to a vet already.

Comment: Went to the vet. He does have a small rash, but after further testing it appears to be the remains of a fight, not a skin disease.

Comment: So we could say he's okay now?

Comment: Yep ! He purrfectly is !

Answer (score 0):

That looks like normal scenting behavior. Cats have scent glands on their forehead and on other parts of their bodies. They will rub their heads like that on things to leave their scent and mark their territory.  Some cats scent things more than others.

If your cat had an eye infection you would notice redness, swelling and possibly a yucky discharge. The video of your cat was very brief but his eyes did not appear to be infected.